# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Elements Stacking - navbar-brand not scaling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to get my site's navbar-brand text to be responsive: I want it to get smaller as the screen is resized. Right now, what happens is that my brand text won't change size on mobile. This creates an ugly stacking of the navbar links over the navbar-brand. I've tried putting

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 14px;
}
}
```

in my CSS, but to no avail. Is there something simple that I'm missing?

Here's a screenshot, to show you what I mean:

[Medium-sized screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxgpT.png)

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Sample Company Law Group, Inc.</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.html">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="attorneys.html">Attorneys</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="practice-areas.html">Practice Areas</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                <a href="references.html">References</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/frzbpkjk/

Comment: so you dont want it to collapse? or is it that you want the title to shrink also

Comment: Please show us a little more of your HTML and CSS (the navbar especially) *To post your code in a snippet all you do is edit your question, press Ctrl+M, and paste the code into the appropriate boxes, then click Insert Into Post, and Save your updated question*

Comment: Please post a working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Will update with relevant CSS and HTML snippets. To clarify, I want the navbar-brand element to shrink as the screen is resized. I want to keep the navbar collapsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I tested your css and it works. You can see an example working on this link:

http://codepen.io/eMineiro/pen/Kzjymp

```
<div class="navbar-brand">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

1) The problem could be on your css code. Check if you have another "font-size" that may be overloading your code.

2) The most easily way to see what is happening is to open you browser developer tools and check what style browser is calling when your media screen is less than 400px

Any example below could override your code:

```
/* Any media with max-width greater than 400px could override your code  */
@media (max-width: 500px) {  
.navbar-brand {
    font-size: XXpx;
}
}
/* Any media with min-width lower than 400px could override your code  */
@media (min-width: 200px) {  
.navbar-brand {
    font-size: XXpx;
}
}
/* Any media with max-width greater than 400px could override your code  */
@media (max-width: 500px) {  
.navbar-brand {
    font-size: XXpx;
}
}
/* Any media with min-width lower than 400px could override your code and max-width greater than 400px */
@media (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 500px) {  
.navbar-brand {
    font-size: XXpx;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-brand class is overriding the (max-width: 400px) navbar-brand class for some reason. Any ideas on how I could fix this? Right now, I have the mobile class above the desktop one, and this problem is still happening.

Comment: "min-width:768px" will not override "max-width: 400px". Each one has values for different resolutions. If your screen has less than 767px, all the CSS in "min-width:768px" will be invalid. I suggest you to use "inspect element". So you could see what's giving "navbar-brand"  a higher font-size.

Comment: Cameron, the comment of Alberto Rubio is right. Check if theres an (max-width: X) overriding your code.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. There was another navbar-brand overriding my mobile style. Everything works just as it should now.